# When is a good time for me to change the billing address of my debit card?

Tags: debit-card

So I'll most likely move from Washington to Rhode Island over the summer, and I'd like to change the billing address of my Bank of America debit card sooner rather than later since I have to pay sales tax for Amazon and Steam purchases for things I buy online (as both Amazon and Steam are hosted in Washington state). So if I do that, would I need to get a new debit card? And what are some possible hassles that I might face in doing it?

Comment: I don't think the address of the billing card has anything to do with sales tax collection; it is the delivery address that determines what sales tax is collected on a purchase made on-line or on the phone. If I order an item to be sent to myself (or anyone else) from, say, Sears which has outlets in all states, the sales tax collected is that for the state where the item is delivered.

Comment: Debit cards don't get billed; they are tied directly to an account from which money is withdrawn.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, it's probably best to keep your credit and debit card billing addresses set to the address you currently inhabit. This way all statements and correspondence are sent to your proper address.

If you change your address after you move, mail forwarding should send the statements on to your new address (although delays and errors do happen). If you change your address much before you move, might statements/letters/tax documents from your bank pile up in an empty mailbox?

This is just for the general case though, I'm not sure how it would impact state sales tax.

You might call Bank of America and ask if they have any requirements. Or, if you plan to change banks when you move, ask the new bank. You could conceivably carry 2 debit cards at once if it would help.

Answer (score 3):

I have moved multiple times in the last 5 years but my billing address is still my friend's parent's home where I had crashed at for a few weeks since I entered the U.S.

I have never been charged taxes based on my billing address: Read the comment from Dr. Dilip Sarwate.

The billing address is an artifact of pre-innternet era where they used to send the "bill": hence "billing address".

In today's times of eBills it has only a verification/fraud management value.

Besides that, in the matter of taxes, the state that you reside in might want you to pay a "use tax" if the retailer/vendor did not collect that tax from you. For example, I had to calculate the "use tax" for all articles I bought from Amazon (who did not collect that tax from me)

Comment: +1 for the use tax comment. As a practical matter, I have always found that on-line web sites are more careful when I ask them to ship something _to myself_ at an address other than the billing address on my credit card; less so if I am shipping the item to someone else at a different address, and especially when I indicate that the item is a gift.

Comment: Tell me about it - my CUs used to call me for confirming every such order, but now they know where I really live :-D